# How to detect html5 video playing in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, xfce, scripts, html5

I am using a [script](https://github.com/zfz/lightsOn/blob/master/lightsOn.sh) to delay screensaver in xubuntu 12.04 while video playing.

However, the script can only detect flash player in Google Chrome. I want to add a new function to detect html5 video playing. I searched a lot but didn't find the shell command to detect html5 video process in Google Chrome.

Could anybody give me some suggestion about it？ Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had [the same question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/78367/37944) on Ubuntu & Unix Stack Exchange site and I understood that:

> The HTML 5 "player" doesn't have any corresponding plugin and the code
>   for it  is embedded directly into the browser. So **you won't see a
>   process getting forked from Chrome when it's dealing with this type of
>   content.**

Thanks to [slm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7453/slm) for [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78680/37944).

Related: [How can I determine if HTML5 player is running in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17020031/2353900)